# Store loop's value in localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, checkbox, local-storage

Good day! I have this code, which show/hide elements when checkboxes are checked/unchecked.

> [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u7s6p5fj/2/)

So it works nice, but I want to store some user's choice in `localStorage` and even after reloading the page this choice will remain. As you can see I am using loop to check which `checkboxes` are true. I have never used `localStorage` before, so any advice and suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Follow the link http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp. Hope this helps in knowing localstorage better

Comment: @Praveen of course I have read about localStorage before asking. But I didn't find any similar solution to my problem(with loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is an answer to my question.

```
  var showHideColInTablle = function () {
  console.log(checkboxToTdBinding);
  var checkedList = checkboxToTdBinding.map(function (checkBox) {
    var c = {}; 
    c[checkBox.checkbox.attr('id')] = checkBox.checkbox.is(":checked");
    return c
  });
       localStorage['checked'] = JSON.stringify(checkedList);
       console.log(typeof localStorage['checked'])
};
```